# IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Exercise:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def format(self, mode):
        if mode == "order":
            return "{2} - {1} - {0}".format(*self.args)

ex = Exercise()
s = ex.format('order').format('third', 'second', 'first')
print(s)
```

I tried running this code but it returned the error as stated in the title. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you expect this to work. You can't chain method calls and assume it's going to remember "something" (like state) between calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting with `self.args` in the `format()` method.

```
            return "{2} - {1} - {0}".format(*self.args)
```

But you have not passed any `args` to the initializer:

```
ex = Exercise()
```

And when calling that method, you are calling `format` on the return value of that method:

```
s = ex.format('order').format('third', 'second', 'first')
```

Which is effectively:

```
"{2} - {1} - {0}".format([])
```

Leading to the error. You should pass the format arguments to the class initializer:

```
ex = Exercise('third', 'second', 'first')
s = ex.format('order')
print(s)
```

Alternatively, to make the code work you can do this:

```
class Exercise:

    def format(self, mode):
        if mode == "order":
            return "{2} - {1} - {0}"
```

Which should work with the rest of your code unchanged

Comment: Why would you create this method and not use `__repr__` or `__str__`?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure they don't because they're chaining method calls that don't return anything

Comment: But that was not the question that they asked.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work by only making changes to the method?  This is a training material that I am following and it says that `s = ex.format('order').format('third', 'second', 'first')` should return the result `first - second - third`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the format arguments to the class initializer, Here how your code should be :

```
class Exercise:
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args

def format(self, mode):
    if mode == "order":
        return "{} - {} - {}".format(*self.args)
ex = Exercise('third', 'second', 'first')
s = ex.format('order')
print(s)
```